# Looking for font with music player controls: loop all, loop once, shuffle

Tags: fonts

Any suggestions? I searched FontSpring, FontSquirrel, and MyFonts to no avail.

Comment: why do you want this in a font?

Comment: I would echo this; typically this isn't done as a font but rather as controls within the UI. If you're looking for free buttons there are a multitude (nay, a plethora) of free and affordable controls out on the interwebs.

Comment: It is incredibly useful to be able to style pictures that would ordinarily be images with CSS -- that's the point.

Comment: See the following reference: http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/ . @lawndartcatcher

Comment: @verve The site you linked has links to collections of fonts, of which at least one contains the controls you are looking for.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Farray Thanks for checking! You're about right. I just can't find a "loop once." (Click the loop button in the desktop version of iTunes to see what I mean.) I may pursue a workaround where I display a 1 over a loop icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using SVG instead of fonts? Not sure below collection has 'loop once' icon but worth checking it out.

www.thenounproject.com

Also I think Itunes' 'loop once' icon is done with '1' in a circle right?

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings-2.html go down to 'J' or 'U'

You might try to overlay the 'circled 1' with CSS on top of your loop icon.